# CCRenderTexture eats up my memory

Tags: ios, memory, cocos2d-iphone, textures

I try to render textures in a background thread in cocos2d and its going well, except that for some reason i am not able to release the textures when no longer used.

First a load two images async, then I run a background task where I render a new image. As I say it's working all fine, problem is my app crashes after calling these functions a few times. I have no idea how to do more cleanup. Logging out my available memory tells me I am losing between 10-15 mb each time (gfx1 and gfx2 are retina fullscreen backgrounds).

The problem must be within these lines of code, for when I remove them I have no memory issues anymore, and profiling my app says there are no leaks!

Textures is a `NSMutableArray`. I have a texture at index 0, render a new one and add it at position 1. After replacing the sprite, I try to kill my (now old) texture at index 0, and my new texture becomes index 0, so i can run this function all over again.

So here is the code

```
- (void) startBuildingTextureInBackground {
    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImageAsync:@"gfx1.png"
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(imageLoaded:)];
}

- (void) imageLoaded: (id) obj {
    rtxTexture1 = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] textureForKey:@"gfx1.png"];
    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImageAsync:@"gfx2.png"
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(imageLoaded2:)];
}

- (void) imageLoaded2: (id) obj {
    rtxTexture2 = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] textureForKey:@"gfx2.png"];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(buildRtxTexture) withObject:nil];
}

- (void) buildRtxTexture {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    EAGLSharegroup *sharegroup = [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] context] sharegroup];
    EAGLContext *k_context = [[[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1 sharegroup:sharegroup] autorelease];
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:k_context];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setGLDefaultValues];

    CCSprite* gfx1 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rtxTexture1];
    [rendernode addChild:gfx1];

    CCSprite* gfx2 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rtxTexture2];
    [rendernode addChild:gfx2];

    CCRenderTexture* rtx = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:512
                                                            height:320
                                                       pixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];

    [rtx beginWithClear:0 g:0 b:0 a:0];
    [rendernode visit];

    [rtx end];

    [rendernode removeChild:gfx1 cleanup:YES];
    [rendernode removeChild:gfx2 cleanup:YES]; 

    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture:rtxTexture1];
    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture:rtxTexture2];

    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(textureLoaded:) withObject:rtx.sprite.texture waitUntilDone:YES]; 

    [pool release];
}

- (void) textureLoaded:(CCTexture2D*) newTexture {
    [textures addObject:newTexture];
}

- (void) replaceTexture {
    if (rtxSprite != nil) {
        [spriteDisplay removeChild:rtxSprite cleanup:YES];
        [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeTexture:[textures objectAtIndex:0]];
        [textures removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }

    rtxSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:[textures objectAtIndex:0]];
    rtxSprite.scaleY = -1;
    [spriteDisplay addChild: rtxSprite];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to debug your code: add break points or NSLog/CCLOG's to track calls of CCTexture2D/CCRenderTexture init/dealloc methods.
2. You have potential issue with CCRenderTexture in background thread. When I try to use CCRenderTexture to manipulate textures the result was unexpected (black texture or crash). This is because in the main loop calls OpenGL functions also and OpenGL is state machine. Workaround was to call method with CCRenderTexture in main thread (performSelectorOnMainThread).

Answer (score 0):

Calling `[pool release]` before setting context to nil solves the problem.